# How to serialize a protobuf object to Ehcache?

Tags: protocol-buffers, ehcache

I have millions of objects, and I need to save them into cache. To reduce the size of these objects and the time of serialization/deserialization, I use protobuf object instead of POJO, then save them into Ehcache as byte array. But Ehcache will put protobuf byte array into an Ehcache's object, and then serialize the object into memory, so the advantage of using protobuf has gone.

Can I just save protobuf object's byte presentation directly into the Ehcache?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Ehcache will put protobuf byte array into an Ehcache's object", I guess you are referring to net.sf.ehcache.Element, right ? But "and then serialize the object into memory", what do you mean here ? 
Just to clarify, Ehcache does not serialize anything to be stored on heap. If you talk about offHeap storage, then yes stuff gets serialized. But if you store byte arrays, serializing these values is... straightforward. Also, you shouldn't worry about internal datastructure serialization, these are handled *very* specifically and even if you'd be able to use protobuf there, you wouldn't gain anything.

But all the benefits you get on using protobuf for your domain instances vs. plain Java serialization, you wouldn't loose.